# Adding a icon on the first item on listview: scrolling it, the icon moves randomly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I have a listview, a custom one and I want to have a plus icon on left side of the first item. Only in the first item!

I wrote my custom adapter and in the getView() method and i used an if condition like this:

```
If position == 0

imgicon.setvisibility=0;

}

else

{
imgicon.setvisibility=1;
}
```

but when i scroll the list up and down, not only the first item displays the icon, but also some randomly items display that icon too. What is wrong? Is this a bug?

**Edit:** not to mention that if I remove the line: `imgicon.setvisibility==0`, all icons disappear.

edit:

here is my custom array adapter:

```
public class Projects_list_custom_array extends ArrayAdapter<Project_Detail> implements
    Filterable {
private final Object mLock = new Object();
private ItemsFilter mFilter;
public ArrayList<Project_Detail> mItems;
private ArrayList<Project_Detail> objects;

public Projects_list_custom_array(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Project_Detail> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
    this.mItems = new ArrayList<Project_Detail>(objects);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_placeholder_projects_list,
                null);
    }

    Project_Detail i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView tt = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.projects_list_first_placeholder);

        RelativeLayout projects_list_layout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.projects_list_placeholder_layout);

        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText(i.get_projectname() + " " + position);
        }

        if (position == 0) {

            ImageView imgv = new ImageView(getContext());
            imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.project_add);
            projects_list_layout.addView(imgv);


        }


    }

    return v;

}

/* ... */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Project_Detail getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}
```

Comment: edit: codes were added in the first post.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding an ImageView dynamically to your layout, you should make it a part of the xml layout and play with its visibility.

So assuming that you have added it to your layout, here's what that part of the code should look like -

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.some_id);
if(position == 0)
      iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
      iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The else part is important since the adapters reuse views. This is the reason why you had some random elements with the 'plus' icon

Answer (score 0):

OK, we need to see your full code to get an idea of what's wrong here. Can you show us the actual Java / XML files?

First of all, what's the default value for the visibility on your list items? Make sure that the plus button is set to View.GONE by default, and that the list items are set to View.VISIBLE.

Secondly, are you duplicating the same view for each list item? Does that mean that all imgicons have the same ID? Maybe you should programmatically insert the imgicon into the first list element, and ONLY the first list element.

Comment: You mean dynamically create the imgicon for the first item?

Comment: Yes. Without knowing the details of your setup I'm not sure why it would be necessary, but it's worth a try. If each list item is nested in a RelativeLayout you should be able to dynamically add something else to the RelativeLayout. It should simplify things.

Comment: I updated the first post. I tried to create the imageview dynamically, but random items still create that imageview again. if i remove the imageview creation code, non of the items display an icon. what is wrong?

Comment: I found out that if remove the if (v == null) condition, it works. but why? Does it affect the efficiency negatively if i remove that if condition?

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I know. ConvertView is usually an existing view; as the list scrolls, you get passed ConvertView and have the option of re-using it. Say that v != null and you don't re-instantiate the view. ConvertView may have, at one time, been the first item in the view. Therefore, if you don't re-instantiate the view, the plus sign will not be "cleared." Does that make sense?

By removing the null check you're being slightly less efficient, but it makes the logic MUCH simpler.

Comment: Also, I may be wrong on this, but it's usually good practice to have convertView = v at the end, before you return v.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the actual `Java / XML files?`

but basic idea is:
first of all in your XML(`R.layout.activity_placeholder_projects_list`) file add one `imagebutton` and then in java use  `if(position==0){//set visibility to Visible}else{//set visibility to gone}. in getview().`